# Showing formally that $H:=\langle x,y| x^2, y^n, yxyx^{-1} \rangle$ is a presentation of $D_{2n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

I want to Show formally that $H:=\langle x,y| x^2, y^n, yxyx^{-1} \rangle$ is a presentation of $D_{2n}$. To start with, by the universal property of the free group, there is a group homomorphism $\phi: H \to D_{2n}$. Then it remains to show that the kernel of $\phi$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing $x^2, y^n, yxyx^{-1}$. I am so confused as to how to prove this, because all of the sources that I found never prove this directly by definition. Most of them even do not mention that we need to prove this. But isn't this the definition of the group presentation?

My $D_{2n}$ is defined to be the group of symmetries of an $n-gon$, and assume that I know $ D_{2n} = \{e, a, b, b^1, \ldots, b^{n-1}, ba, \ldots, b^{n-1}a\}$, where $a^2 = e$, $b^n = e$ and $ab = b^{-1}a$.

Comment: A lot depends on what definition you are using for $D_{2n}$.

Comment: Do you know about semidirect products? One way to approach this question would be to view your group as the semidirect product of two cyclic groups. You can then work out what the presentation of semidirect products look like (this is how I first came across presentations).

Answer (score 4):

First, note that you know that these relators are all required (although in theory some may be degenerate), as you have pointed out, so we have a surjective homomorphism $\phi: H\rightarrow D_{2n}$.

> **Task** (left to reader). Show that every element in $H$ may be written in the form $y^ix^j$ for some integers $i\in\{0, 1\}$ and $j\in\{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$.

Once you have completed this task then the result follows, as it says that $H$ has order at most $2n$. Therefore, as $\phi$ is surjective onto a group with $2n$ elements, $\phi$ must infact be bijective and so an isomorphism.

---

My use of cardinalities in the last paragraph is unnecessary. You can clearly see that it is a bijection without using cardinalities. This idea then generalises to semidirect products (and further to all extensions, but that is more complicated): If $G=N\rtimes H$ and $H$ acts on $N$ via the automorphism $\varphi\in\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ then $G$ has the relative presentation* $\langle H, N\mid hnh^{-1}=\varphi(n)\rangle$, and that this is actually a relative presentation for $G$ is proved using the same ideas as above.

*To get an actual presentation for $G$ you add in generators and relators for $N$ and $H$ in the hopefully obvious way...

Comment: I see. I actually made a mistake in my description, and I meant to say, there is a homomorphism from $F\{x,y\} \to D_{2n}$. Then to get a homo from $H \to D_{2n}$, one needs to show it sends the normal subgroup generated by those relations to identity. How does that work? I think it is confusing, because I generally do not know a good description of the normal subgroup generated by elements. I can probably get around this by showing that the subgroup generated by those elements are sent to identity. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, okay. I had actually typed out a longer answer but spotted that you were mapping from $H$ to $D_{2n}$. However, this really is the "easy" bit - you know that $a^2=e$, $b^n=e$ and $ab=b^{-1}a$, so you force these identities to occur in the group by hard-coding them into the presentation. So that is where the presentation for $H$ comes from - you require $x^2$, $y^n$ and $aba^{-1}b$ to be in your normal subgroup.

Comment: (I am in a rush just now and just skimmed your comment. Please tell me if you want more detail and I can add it in later.)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is pretty enlightening. There is just one more thing that I want to know: How do you show formally that all the element in the normal subgroup generated by the relations are mapped to the identity element? Is it becasue you can write them as the products of $x^2, y^n, yxyx^{-1}$?

Comment: They are mapped to the identity because of the first isomorphism theorem - our normal subgroup $N$ corresponds to a homomorphism $\varphi: F\rightarrow H$ such that $N=\ker\varphi$. So every element of $N$ is mapped to the identity in $H$.